# Modify global module variable externally

Tags: python

I have a plotting module imported by other scripts/jupyter notebooks which has a global variable denoting font size on the axis labels.  This variable is used as default for a function setting axis labels:

```py
FONT_SIZE=14
def pltlabel(title='', x='', y='', size=FONT_SIZE):
    """ this function is used by other functions within the same module"""
    plt.title(title, fontsize=size)
    plt.xlabel(x, fontsize=size)
    plt.ylabel(y, fontsize=size)
```

In some scenarios I want to change this font globally.  I've tried creating a function to do so

```py
def change_global_fontsize(s):
    global FONT_SIZE
    FONT_SIZE = s
```

and calling in the notebook where plotting takes place, but it doesn't really change the value of the global, as I can see when I call my plotting functions.

I do see why this is happening - value of data from a module is essentially unidirectional, and once it's imported it cannot be changed within the module.

What is the best approach for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that default function argument values are only evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time it is called.  So the right-hand side of `size=FONT_SIZE` is only evaluated once, and that is used as the default value for `size` for any future function calls.

You should use `FONT_SIZE` as the default inside the function so it gets the current value each time.  Specifically, set `size=None` as the default argument, and replace inside the function, eg:

```py
FONT_SIZE=14
def pltlabel(title='', x='', y='', size=None)
    if size is None:
        size = FONT_SIZE
    ...
```

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).